# read and clone json array

Tags: angular, typescript

Problem with the form of my `json` array when worked with my static array

**Output**-

```
[
    {id: '1', officename: 'Sun '},
    {id: '2', officename: 'Moon'},
    {id: '3', officename: 'Stars'},

  ]; `
```

and I cloned it to another array , but didn't get the data from `API` of another format, array is displayed.

the format of array used-

[image]

compare the 2 json output

[image]

Need to use this format in current array

[image]

Cloned `function`

> cloneArray(x) {
>       return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)); // returns Array   }
>   part of mt code

```
 private k: Array<any>;

  @Input() confMedia2: Array<any> = [];
   confMedia: Array<any> = [
    {id: '1', officename: 'Sun'},
    {id: '2', officename: 'Moon'},
    {id: '4', officename: 'Stars1'},
    {id: '6', officename: 'Stars3'},
    {id: '7', officename: 'Stars4'},
    {id: '8', officename: 'Stars5'},
    {id: '9', officename: 'Stars6'},
    {id: '10', officename: 'Stars7'},
  ];

  // temp
  allMedia: Array<any> = [];
  // a: Array<any> = [];
  selectedMedia: Array<any> = [];



   // the code i use to map the  data from api to an other component to confMedia2
     private getNestedData(id: any) {
    this.api.getConfiguration(id).subscribe(data => {
      // data.m(r => this.ConfMedias = r.medias);
      // data.medias.map(r =>  this.Tarrah.push(r));
      // regularUrls = regularUrls.concat(region.damageDetails.map(damage => damage.regularUrl));
      // this.Tarrah = this.Tarrah.concat(data.medias.map(damage => damage));
      this.Tarrah.push(data.medias);
    });
    console.log( 'b', this.Tarrah);
  }
  constructor() {
    // clone media on all media array to manipulate
    this.allMedia = this.cloneArray(this.medias);
    // this.a = this.cloneArray(this.medias1);
    this.selectedMedia = this.cloneArray(this.confMedia);
    this.aff();}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know your reqiurement. But, the array clone I used it `this.tempArray = [...Array.from(new Set(this.array))];` try it @iheb chaaraoul

Comment: `let currentArray = cloneArray(existingArray)` no?

Comment: yes i use it  like this but it give me 0 in the cloned array i have a problem with the index 0 of the mapped array @Malcor

Comment: with the first array no problem

Comment: Can I see that part of your code?@iheb chaaraoul

Comment: @JaiKumaresh  i add the code in the post

Comment: I think you problem is in `console.log( 'b', this.Tarrah);` try it`this.Tarrah.push(data.medias); ---> this.Tarrah = [...Array.from(new Set(data.medias))];` try it

Comment: You can submit these types of queries in the communities or chat rooms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the

```
this.Tarrah.push(data.medias);
```

that give a different form for clon function can't clone i change affection function with tradutional way like this

```
this.Tarrah = data.medias
```

thank you all for your help and i wish my code be beneficial for others developers

Answer (score 0):

clone an  array:
const myClonningArray  = Object.assign([], myArray);

for clone an object try this:
const myCloneObject = Object.assign({}, myObject);

Answer (score 0):

The above solution array clone is not worked.

[image]

My worked solution is

Clone for array:
`this.tempArray = [...Array.from(new Set(this.array))];`

Clone for object:
`this.tempObj = Object.assign({}, this.obj);`

Comment: my problem jai is not to clone the problem is format of json i get from api `

Comment: my problem jai is not to clone the problem is format of json i get not same of i use in